# why getting errors in c++ program?

Tags: c++, class, object

I think I have coded everything correctly in this program but still getting errors.
The object `si` it says it's not accessible.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>

class s_interest
{
    int p,t;
    float r;
    s_interest(int a, int b, float c)
    {
        p=a;
        r=b;
        t=c;
    }

    void method()
    {
        int result=(float)(p*t*r)/100;
        cout<<"Simple interest:"<<result;
    }
};

void main()
{
    int pr,ti;
    float ra;
    cout<<"\n Enter the principle, rate of interest and time to calculate Simple Interest:";
    cin>>pr>>ti>>ra;
    s_interest si(pr,ti,ra);
    si.method();
}
```

Comment: The title and the explanation is not really good. Please, next time, specify your problem in the title at least.

Answer (score 5):

When the compiler tells you that something is not accessible, it's talking about the `public:` vs. `protected:` vs. `private:` access control. By default, all members of a class are `private:`, so you cannot access any of them from `main()`, including the constructor and the method.

To make the constructor `public`, add a `public:` section to your class, and put the constructor and the method there:

```
class s_interest
{
    int p,t;
    float r;
public: // <<== Add this
    s_interest(int a, int b, float c)
    {
        ...
    }
    void method()
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Default member access for a `class` is `private` (whereas the default for `struct` is `public`). You need to make the constructor and `method()` `public`:

```
class s_interest
{
  int p,t;  // private
  float r;  // also private


public: // everything that follows has public access

  s_interest(int a, int b, float c) { .... }
  void method() { ....}
};
```

Note also that `void main()` is not standard C++. The return type needs to be `int`, so you need

```
int main()
{
  ...
}
```

And finally, `iostream.h` is not a standard C++ header. You need to include `<iostream>` if you are using a standards compliant C++  implementation.

Comment: Why everybody keep saying use `iostream` instead of  `iostream.h`? I agree that `iostream.h` is not a standard header, but along with saying this, compiler change also needs to be pointed out, if OP uses some decade old compiler like Turbo C++ and simply changing this header, will throw a compiler error.

Comment: @P0W We are talking about standard C++ here. If a question refers to a pre-standards compiler, then it should be up to OP to point that requirement out. In any case, I have qualified my last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Following **High Integrity C++ Coding Standard** guidelines, always declare first *public*, then protected and private members. See [Rule 3.1.1 of hicpp-manual-version-3-3.pdf](http://www.programmingresearch.com/content/misc/hicpp-manual-version-3-3.pdf#page18)

Comment: About 4 days after you answered this question, HIC++ V4.0 was uploaded to http://www.codingstandard.com/section/index/.  The rules were completely rewritten, mainly to cover C++ language features since 2011. As it happens, there is no longer a rule regarding the order of accessibility for members in a class.

Answer (score 0):

All the variables & functions in your class are private. This is the default when access is not specified with the `private:` , `protected:` and `public:` specifiers. I suggest you have a good read of a tutorial - google C++ classes.

also it is `int main()` and never `void main()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to access specifiers. By default class methods and data members are private. Make your data members private and methods public. so you can set the private data members value using public methods.

```
class{
private:
int a;
int b;
int c;
public:

void method();
void print_sum();

};
```